# Bug in python while loop... Need Python advice

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop, global

I am trying to set a variable (not a global variable, this wont work with my threading) in a while True loop.

Basically, the while loop runs, buys coin, waits until a macd indicator turns green to signal a ready to sell if variable called "waitwait" and that if statement will set this to true. Then, my desired functionality is it to loop around again and again with that variable set, until I receive the macd down signal and while both statements are true on the sell "elif" statement, I want the system to run the elif statement (while "waitwait" is set to True).

Code is very long, the main code is in the "runrun" def statement here:
https://github.com/TheRoboKitten/ZenAii/blob/master/development2.py

Here is a code sample:

```
def runrun():
    waitwait = False
    print('Waitwait set to False before sell and waiting on macd up signal before sell.')
    while True:
        global sellstr
        global buystr
        global coincoin
        global coin
        global flag
        btcc='BTC_'
        coin= btcc + coincoin
        word=coin
        from poloniex import Poloniex
        api = Poloniex(jsonNums=float)
        df = Chart(api, word).dataFrame()
        df.dropna(inplace=True)
        data = (df.tail(2)[['macd']])
        data1 = (df.tail(2)[['emasig']])
        #Turn Data into a string
        txt=str(data)
        txt1=str(data1)
        # search for floats in the returned data
        re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re2='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 1
        re3='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re4='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 2
        rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        m = rg.search(txt)
        re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re2='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 1
        re3='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re4='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 2
        rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        m1 = rg.search(txt1)
        # Search for floats that are too small to trade decision on
        re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re2='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 1
        re3='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))' # Variable Name 1
        re4='([-+]\\d+)'    # Integer Number 1
        re5='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re6='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 2
        re7='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))' # Variable Name 2
        re8='([-+]\\d+)'    # Integer Number 2
        rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        deny = rg.search(txt)
        re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re2='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 1
        re3='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))' # Variable Name 1
        re4='([-+]\\d+)'    # Integer Number 1
        re5='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
        re6='([+-]?\\d*\\.\\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])'  # Float 2
        re7='((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))' # Variable Name 2
        re8='([-+]\\d+)'    # Integer Number 2
        rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        deny1 = rg.search(txt1)
        # Two if statements to decide what will happen... buy/sell/deny trade on limited data
        print(data)
        print(data1)
        if deny and deny1:
            float1=deny.group(1) + deny.group(2) + deny.group(3)
            float2=deny.group(4) + deny.group(5) + deny.group(6)
            float3 = float(float1)
            float4 = float(float2)
            float5=deny1.group(1) + deny1.group(2) + deny1.group(3)
            float6=deny1.group(4) + deny1.group(5) + deny1.group(6)
            float7 = float(float5)
            float8 = float(float6)
            print(float3, float4, float7, float8)
            # Calculate the difference in the two numbers
            diff = Decimal(float(float7 - float3))
            diff1 = Decimal(float(float8 - float4))
            diffstr = str(diff)
            diffstr1 = str(diff1)
            diff4 = (diff1 - diff)
            diff4str=str(diff4)
            print(diffstr1)
            print('Buying ' + word + ' on error correction loop.')
            ke1=word.replace('BTC_', '')
            ke3='-BTC'
            ke8=ke1+ke3
            buystr=ke8
            buybuy()

            # HERE DIFF 4 IS HISTOGRAM SIGNAL ON UPTREND. DIFF 1 IS ACTUAL MACD SIGNAL
            if (Decimal(diff1) > 1):
                waitwait = True
                print('Waiting... MACD is on UP signal for: ' + word)

            elif (Decimal(diff1) < 0)and (waitwait == True):
                print(word)
                print('Current macd hist diff is: ' + diff4str)
                sellstr=ke8
                print('Selling... MACD is on DOWN Signal for: ' + word)
                sellsell()
                break
            else:
                print(word)
                print('Current macd diff is: ' + diff4str)
                print('Waiting for MACD UP Signal for: ' + word)
```

Comment: There's not much we can do with this question - you haven't specified what bug you're encountering, your code is large and difficult to follow, and relatively out of context. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Your code has tons of repetitions. Clean them up, use constantes like `FLOAT_REGEX = ...` and reuse them, use raw strings to make the regular expressions a little more readable...

Comment: My bug is that every time the while loop is run, and loops, the statement is set to false instead of true from the original if statement. Declaring the ready statement "waitwait" ready to sell.

Comment: Your code is a mess. Clean it up, which makes it easier for everyone to read and understand. While doing this, you will probably find the bug yourself. For algorithmic trading, I'd recommend [PyAlgoTrade](http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/). This will probably have less bugs than your own homebrew code.

Comment: Additionally: it is totally unclear for me why you do all the regex's...

Comment: If you would click the link you would see that I calculate macd on the spot, to an accuracy far better than any other using scientific notation. It outputs this into a tail where I get most of my data from in the last 10 minutes.